# React Native (iOS): Splash Screen doesn't disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am developing an app in react native and have set up a splash screen using [react-native-bootsplash](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash). The library has a method to hide the splash screen and I set up a function so that the splash screen is hidden properly.

For Android, it is hidden without any problem, but for iOS, it is not being hidden. When I checked with console.log(), the function is being invoked, but the splash screen remains there. I suspect the splash screen is loaded multiple times for iOS specifically and I suspect there is something wrong with my AppDelegate.m. It does not look wrong, but I have no experience in iOS native development so can't be sure.

Can someone take a look and advise where I went wrong? Below is my AppDelgate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNFBMessagingModule.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RNBootSplash.h"
#import "FBSDKCoreKit.h"


#if DEBUG
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
    FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
    SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
    [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
    [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
    [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    #if DEBUG
        InitializeFlipper(application);
    #endif
        [FIRApp configure];
        [FBSDKApplicationDelegate initializeSDK:launchOptions];

        RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
        RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"AppName" initialProperties:nil];
        rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
        rootViewController.view = rootView;
        self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView];

    return YES;

}

-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
    #ifdef DEBUG
        return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
    #else
        return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
    #endif
}


@end
```

My AppDelegate. h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: Splash screen is a user-friendly mechanism. Why do you want to hide it?